# How can i generate a network graph which is part random and part arbitrary in R

Tags: r, social-networking, igraph

I have a table with data for a network graph. The table is as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(ResponseID = 
   c('573829292', '638239391', '630719030', '632932937'), 
   know_anyone = c(9,16,12,32))
```

How can i generate a  network graph were each ResponseID is a node randomly connected to other ResponseID's but also connected in a star-like manner to a number of other nodes represented by the numbers in the 'know_anyone' column?

Comment: Please provide the data as text in your question.  We cannot cut and paste from your image.

Comment: I am having some formatting problems but, I will trying format the data so that it could be readable.

Comment: So your final graph will have those four plus an extra 9+16+12+32 nodes? And we can give those extra 69 nodes unique IDs?

Comment: The data is just a snippet from a larger data frame of about 1000 rows. Each row will represent a node connected to other nodes randomly. So indeed the network would comprise approximately 1000 nodes plus the 9+6+12+23, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make a data frame repeating the ID the `know_anyone` number of times with a node sequence number from 1 to N:

```
> dstars = data.frame(
   src=rep(df$ResponseID,df$know_anyone),
   dst=paste0("N",1:(sum(df$know_anyone))))
```

Then create a your random graph however. I'll create a full graph for the original nodes by getting all the combinations of two number from 1 to M (M=4 here). Rbind that, or your graph from the connections between the original nodes, to the above and make a graph:

```
> g = graph.data.frame(
      rbind(
       data.frame(
          src=df$ResponseID[combn(nrow(df),2[1,]],
          dst=df$ResponseID[combn(nrow(df),2)[2,]]
       ),
       dstars)
     )
```

Don't use this for your 1000 nodes, because that will make a graph with half a million edges - I assume your random graph will have fewer than that (or you have more RAM than I do!).

Comment: I am getting the following error from the first code: Error in rep(reg4$ResponseID, reg4$know_anyone) : 
  invalid 'times' argument

Comment: Is your `reg4$know_anyone` column numeric, greater than or equal to zero, and with no "NA" missing values? What's `sum(is.na(reg4$know_anyone))`?

Comment: I figured it out - the column had missing values.

Comment: your solution has way too much connections. My idea is that ResponseID's would have been connected to each other maybe once in a circle like manner and each responseID's would also be connected to a number of other nodes specified by know_anyone, preferably in a star-like manner.

Comment: yeah, I just needed some way of connecting the original nodes up and plumped for a complete graph!

Comment: How about connecting the original nodes (n) in a way that the number of edges will be n-1? In such case each of the original nodes will have at most two edges to the nearest neighbor and no more. But each original nodes will also be attached to an arbitrary number of other nodes represented by the numbers in 'know_anyone' column. So for example, if the know_anyone column has the number 3 then the original node associated with that cell will have 5 edges - two from the previous connections and three more to the new nodes. @Spacedman

Comment: Can you figure out how to do that yourself? Just create a data frame of two columns with row IDs and use graph.data.frame.